# I need an array which vaires from different sizes of n and it needs to correspond to a given list

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, algorithm

this is what I've got so far but I don't know what to do
    ` Sub SetUpList()
            Dim UnsortedList(1 To 100000, 1 To 1) As Double
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To 100000
                UnsortedList(i, 1) = Rnd(-i)
            Next i
            Range("A1:A100000").value = UnsortedList
        End Sub

```
    Sub InitializeA()

        Dim i As Long

        n = Cells(2, 2).value
        ReDim A(1 To n)
                For i = 1 To n
            A(i) = Cells(i, 1).value
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just size the `Range` to what you need, then pull all the values into an array at once?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please visit the page: [How to ask a good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because your post has no description of the problem, and there is no clear question being asked here.

Comment: What is your problem?  What do you want to do?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  basically i need a macro that will read the first n elements of this data from the spreadsheet, and store them in A. I want to consider different sizes of A (up to a maximum of 100,000), and so I will also read a value for n from cell B2 in the spreadsheet. Given n, I can then redim A to the right size, and then use a loop i from 1 to n to enter the value in Cells(i,1) into the array entry A(i).

Comment: @Comintern because my range can vary between values of 1 to 100000

Comment: Your posted code seems to be doing just tjst

Comment: I get that.  But if you call `.Value` on a `Range` like `Range("A1:A100000")` it gives you an array with elements 1 to 100000 in it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld that's the problem it isn't. when i run the macro nothing happens and i have entered a value in n. but i don't  think  n actually corresponds to the list

Comment: @Comintern oh i get you in terms of calling it but then how would i link it to n

Comment: `Range("A1:A" & n)`

Comment: I'll second @Comintern on pulling the range into an array dynamically. There are ways to determine the range size first, then only pull in the desired range. We would need more details first, though.

Comment: @Comintern so should i make that equal to the array?

Comment: No, `Range("A1:A" & n).Value` ***is*** the array.

Comment: @Comintern oh okay i get you. the thing is that my array has to go up to 100,000 and it has to be a global variable as well as a dynamic array

Comment: @JonathanAkinrele  When I run your code here, the vba variant array you have named `A` gets filled with the number of elements form column A equal to `n`.  Of course, you have to run `InitializeA` immediately after `SetupList`.  If you change the active worksheet in between, it won't work.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it actually does not work on mine. I have tried running the code on vba in excel and literally nothing happens. I have not changed the active worksheet in between either

Comment: I just need to know how to print it into the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method to print a section of your list onto your spreadsheet.

```
Option Explicit
'this generates the list and I need to create an array from this list for different sizes of n
Sub SetUpList()
    Dim UnsortedList(1 To 100000, 1 To 1) As Double
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    Dim A As Variant, R As Range

    For i = 1 To 100000
        UnsortedList(i, 1) = Rnd(-i)
    Next i
    Range("A1:A100000").Value = UnsortedList

    N = Cells(2, 2).Value
    'this allows us to determine the size of the array which will vary because there can be different sizes of n

    Initialize

End Sub

Sub Initialize()
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim UnsortedList As Variant

UnsortedList = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
N = Cells(2, 2)
Set rDest = Range("C1")

ReDim A(1 To N, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To N
        A(i, 1) = UnsortedList(i, 1)
    Next i

    Set rDest = rDest.Resize(rowsize:=N)
    rDest.EntireColumn.Clear
    rDest = A
End Sub
```

Comment: @RonRosenfield thank you for that my code does what I want it to do now. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @JonathanAkinrele Glad to help. If you could mark my response as the answer, I would appreciate it.